# Android Emulator is not working in Android Studio 2.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying run my emulator in Android Studio 2.3.2. It's just coming like this

[image]

and then closing the window. But not launching the emulator.

Here are the details of AVD.

> Name: 5.4_FWVGA_API_22 
>   CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
>   Path: C:\Users\vinod.android\avd\5.4_FWVGA_API_22.avd
>
> Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 22)
>
> Skin: 480x854
>
> SD Card: 100M
>
> hw.dPad: no
>
> runtime.network.speed: full
>
> hw.accelerometer: yes
>
> hw.device.name: 5.4in FWVGA
>
> vm.heapSize: 48
>
> skin.dynamic: yes
>
> hw.device.manufacturer: Generic
>
> hw.gps: yes
>
> hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
>
> skin.path.backup: _no_skin
>
> image.androidVersion.api: 22
>
> hw.audioInput: yes
>
> image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-22\google_apis\x86\
>
> tag.id: google_apis
>
> showDeviceFrame: no
>
> hw.camera.back: emulated
>
> hw.mainKeys: yes
>
> AvdId: 5.4_FWVGA_API_22
>
> hw.camera.front: emulated
>
> hw.lcd.density: 160
>
> avd.ini.displayname: 5.4  FWVGA API 22
>
> hw.gpu.mode: auto
>
> hw.device.hash2: MD5:fbd5143f5b48ba972391c87c302c0c69
>
> hw.ramSize: 512
>
> hw.trackBall: no
>
> PlayStore.enabled: false
>
> hw.battery: yes
>
> hw.cpu.ncore: 2
>
> hw.sdCard: yes
>
> tag.display: Google APIs
>
> runtime.network.latency: none
>
> hw.keyboard: yes
>
> hw.sensors.proximity: yes
>
> disk.dataPartition.size: 800M
>
> hw.sensors.orientation: yes
>
> avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
>
> hw.gpu.enabled: yes

Here is my sdk tools details:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use something like genymotion?

Comment: Any error messages in console?

Comment: no error message

Answer (score 1):

If using Linux, create a symlink for it:

ln -sf /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6  /$HOME/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6

Comment: No I am using Windows OS

Answer (score 0):

try this:-->

> AVD Settings -> Emulated Performance -> Graphics. Set Software - GLES 2.0.